# How to select option from dropdown with exact text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to allow user to type in a text box and look it up in a select dropdown and select it. However I have object itself and not its name.

Currently Pressing enter on text box will run following code

```
$(this).prev().find('option:contains(\'editboxValue\')').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

but above code only selects Text2. following code works fine but it looks messy!

```
$(this).prev().find("option").each(function(){ if ($(this).text() == 'editboxValue') $(this).attr("selected","selected");});
```

is there any better way to write it?

```
<select>
  <option>Text</option>
  <option>Text1</option>
  <option>Text2</option>
</select>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Your `each` loop will never select an element. `'+ $(this).val() +'` is taken literally. You could use `filter`: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for highlighting the mistake. I took the line from part of event attached to select. I edited the code to show what I meant

Answer (score 3):

to select the option using the dropdownlist item text, use this

```
var findText = $('#textBoxId').val();
$('#dropDownList option').
    filter(function () {return ($(this).text() == findText); })).
    attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

give your select an ID or class and give your options the id equal to your text.
Easy to make if you generate the options .
Al you have to do than is this:

```
var myId = 'GetTheIdYouNeed'
$('.mySelect').find(myId);
```

Comment: That would search for an element with **tag name** `GetTheIdYouNeed`.

Comment: This is not the case, I can have multiple selects in page and each of them has the text box after it. 
event is attached to each textbox at runtime, so the are unknown to script